# Webservice failing on startup when built with Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat8

We are building a webservices with Java8 and deploying it to Tomcat8. We get following error during start up.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

When we build the same component with Java7 we are not seeing this issue.

Here is our pom dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is our web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationConfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

ApplicationConfig.xml has the import

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

Please do help. Tried using 3.0.4 and 3.1.8 cxf versions but thats failing in building the application.

Comment: Have you verified that `META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml` exists and is accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: if you are going to down vote an answer please give an explanation. The `cxf-servlet.xml` file is the METE-INF of the `cxf-rt-transports-http` jar, so this answer should solved the problem

Comment: If you are going to answer please give an explanation. That comment should be in your answer with supporting evidence.